# Is it possible to control playing of 3D animation frame by frame using the Heaps game engine?

Tags: haxe

any body using the [heaps](https://heaps.io/) game engine?

1. Is it possible to control 3D animation playing frame by frame programmablely and how?
   I have tried to do it like this: `anim.frame = 10;` but it has no effect.
2. What I’m trying to do is turn 3D animation to 2D sequence animation like what [DeadCells](https://dead-cells.com/) did. My idea is simply rendering every frame of the 3D animation to an image using heaps framework. Is that possible?
3. Could anybody share some base knowledge about the various coordinate spaces used in heaps?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Somebody has answered this in the Heaps Discord channel: https://discordapp.com/channels/162395145352904705/501408700142059520/721272598788571170

Comment: @Gama11 Thanks for the info! But when I open the link it shows an empty page...:(

Comment: `frame` is a read-only property, how did you manage to set it? And did you change the `speed` of the animation to be 0 and/or set `pause` to true?

Comment: @UnholySheep I called the ```setFrame()``` method of the ```Animation``` class. I set the ```pause``` to be true on a keyup event when the animation is playing. But the animation could not be paused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the completeness of this question and convenience of other, I'd like to copy the answer of `Yanrishatum` from Discord to here, as noted by @Gama11 in the comment:

> 1. `myObj.currentAnimation.setFrame`
> 2. `Object.drawTo` onto Texture. Make use Target flag when allocating the texture. 
>         Then you can capturePixels to extract result from GPU to RAM, 
>         then toPNG method of Pixels should give png bytes which can be stored to fs.
> 3. Question too vague. 
>         There's screen space, which is basically only used in events before 
>         you pass thsoe to specific Scene. 
>         Then there's Scene coordinate space. 
>         2d and 3d scenes use their own (what a surprise). 
>         For 3D, Z is up, contrary to many engines that has Y-up orientation.